# GetSnapshotAsync() never returning and I don't get any errors. How can I debug this issue?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying Firestore with the nugget package Google.Cloud.Firestore

I followed this intro [CRUD with firestore](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-with-blazor-using-google-cloud-firestore/)

Using the debugger I can see that the execution of the program stops when trying to call the method Query.GetSnapshotAsync()

I want to get just a list of documents from a collection.

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Results;
using FirestoreAPI.Domain.Restaurants;
using FirestoreAPI.Repository.Restaurants;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FirestoreAPI.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class RestaurantsController : ApiController
    {
        public RestaurantsController() { }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("restaurants")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAllRestaurants()
        {
            //var restAggregate = new RestaurantsAggregate();
            var restaurantsRepo = new RestaurantsRepo();
            return new NegotiatedContentResult<Task<List<Restaurant>>>(
                HttpStatusCode.OK,
                restaurantsRepo.GetAllRestaurants(),
                this
            ); ;
        }
    }
}
```

**DataLayer**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;

namespace FirestoreAPI.Repository.Restaurants
{
    public class RestaurantsRepo
    {
        //public FirestoreConn dbConn;
        string projectId;
        FirestoreDb firestoreDb;
        public RestaurantsRepo()
        {
            //dbConn = new FirestoreConn();
            string credentials = "C:\\Users\\ezequiel.lopez\\projects\\firestoredotnet\\FirestoreAPI\\firestoreapi-dca55-0be2f7d57f41.json";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", credentials);
            projectId = "firestoreapi-dca55";
            firestoreDb = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId);
        }

        public async Task<List<Restaurant>> GetAllRestaurants()
        {
            //FirestoreDb fsDB = dbConn.GetFSConnection();
            //Query query = fsDB.Collection("restaurants").OrderByDescending("avgRating").Limit(50);
            Query query = firestoreDb.Collection("restaurants").OrderByDescending("avgRating").Limit(50);
            QuerySnapshot restSnaps = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
            List<Restaurant> restaurants = new List<Restaurant>();

            return restSnaps.Documents
                            .Where<DocumentSnapshot>(ds => ds.Exists)
                            .Select(ds => ds.ConvertTo<Restaurant>()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Restaurant**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;

namespace FirestoreAPI.Repository.Restaurants
{
    [FirestoreData]
    public class Restaurant
    {   
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public decimal avgRating { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string category { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string city { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public int numRatings { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public int price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. Thing is, I was calling an async method from a synchronous one. It didn't work until I've made my caller method async and awaited for it.