# Task<DocumentSnapshot>.Result.Exists Always Returns False

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new on Firebase Firestore and I trying to check if certain document exist on my database, but my boolean always return false. I'm using C# with Unity and Firebase v9.3.0.

```
public static void CheckIfUserAreRegistered()
{
    DocumentReference doc = Database.Collection("Users").Document(FacebookManager.UserID);

    doc.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        if (task.Result.Exists) UserAreRegistered = DefaultState.Yes;
        else UserAreRegistered = DefaultState.No;
    });

}
```

Here a image of my database data with respective id I'm searching: [image]

I don't know what could be going on, if anyone can help me, I would be immensely grateful.

**Edit**
**==============================================================**

I tried to change the code to use Async/Await operators, despite my Unity not showing any log error, my Visual Studio returns CS1061 exception (Task does not have a definition to "GetAwaiter")

Here my Async/Await code:

```
public static async Task<DocumentSnapshot> WaitForCheckUsers()
{
    DocumentReference doc = Database.Collection("Users").Document(FacebookManager.UserID);

    return await doc.GetSnapshotAsync();
}

public static async void CheckIfUserAreRegistered()
{
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await WaitForCheckUsers();
    if (doc.Exists) UserAreRegistered = DefaultState.Yes;
    else UserAreRegistered = DefaultState.No;
    Debug.Log($"bool: {doc.Exists} UserID: {FacebookManager.UserID} Doc: {doc.Id}");
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: make your method async and await the the result of `GetSnapshotAsync`.  
It is generally no good idea to try to resolve async calls from non-async code (also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261142/getsnapshotasync-never-returning-and-i-dont-get-any-errors-how-can-i-debug-t)

Comment: @JürgenRöhr I was trying to use async and await operator following the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=pt-br#c_1) early and despite my Unity not showing any log error, my Visual Studio returns CS1061 exception (Task<DocumentSnapshot> does not have a definition to "GetAwaiter").

Comment: When you use `GetAwaiter`, you're not coding async. You're still trying to resolve an async call in sync code which generally leads to trouble. Have a look at my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Change you method like this to use it as in the documentation you linked (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=pt-br#c_1)

```cs
public static async Task CheckIfUserAreRegisteredAsync()
{
   DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
   // use snapshot to check users
}
```

Renaming the method to `...Async` is just a convention.

Of course, that would mean that you have to change the method(s) which are calling `CheckIfUserAreRegistered` (and up the complete calling tree).

Comment: I tried to format the code as you sugested, but still returning false.

Comment: Not quite. Your calling method is defined as "async void". You always have to use "async  Task"... up to the topmost method.

Comment: Aside just to make sure: the UserID contains the value from your database?

Comment: Today I changed the void to Task and tried searching another document and it's still returning false. I think I'll switch to Realtime Database.